# How can I prove that F(n)= Theta(T(n))?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

How can I prove that F(n)= Theta(T(n))? I couldn't put the theta symbol in the question. I know theta means equal?

Comment: Why dont you show us what you have already tried. Also this would probably go better on the math SE site.

Comment: What are `F(n)` and `T(n)`?

Comment: F(n) = O(T(n)) and F(n) = Omega(T(n)) => F(n) = Theta(T(n))

Comment: See wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Oh.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question without knowing what F(n) and T(n) are.  Can you provide that information?

Comment: Also, Theta does not mean equal. It only makes a statement on the asymptotics, not the actual value. (e.g. A constant factor could be added)

Answer (score 0):

You should prove the function with the definition of Theta.
That is to say if lim(F(n)/T(n))=c (if n->mega), that means Theta

Answer (score 0):

Show that F(n) = O(T(n)) and that F(n) = Omega(T(n)).

Answer (score -1):

Do a bit of reading on "proof by mathematical induction"
So you say, if something is true for k=1,2...n, then n+1, then it is true for all n. 
There is a good book called "The nuts and bolts of proofs" that shows this method.